# Error with array() function in python-3.x

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, checksum

im new in python.

part of my code is:

```
def _checksum(self, data):

    if sum(len(i) for i in data) & 1:
        data.append('\0')

    **words = array('h', ''.join(data))**
    checksum = 0
    for word in words:
        checksum += word & 0xffff
    hi = checksum >> 16
    low = checksum & 0xffff
    checksum = hi + low
    checksum += (checksum >> 16)
    return ~checksum & 0xffff
```

in python 2 its work, but in python 3 have error:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

i'm understand have problem in code line:

```
words = array('h', ''.join(data))
```

but i not understand how to fix this

thank you for help!

Comment: Is that array() function np.array or something you defined?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is not with `array()`, but its with the `join()` function.

When you use join like

```
words = array('h', ''.join(data))
```

You are using the `str.join` method, which expects all arguments to be string. But in your `data`, the values are `bytes` or atleast the first one is bytes.

If you want to join bytes, then you must use it like

```
words = array('h', b''.join(data))
```

and all values must be bytes in data.